# Custom linear layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I'm trying to make my own LinearLayout to make it reusable and modular.
first my code looked like this, which worked fine:

```
mLlHeader = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.ll_header);
        mTvCrump = new TextView(mContext);
        mTvCrump.setText("> "+((Item) mNavigationHistory.get(mNavigationHistory.size()-1)).getName());
        mTvCrump.setId(mNavigationHistory.size()-1);
        mTvCrump.setClickable(true);
        mTvCrump.setOnClickListener(mBreadcrumpListener);
        mBreadcrump.add(mTvCrump);
        mLlHeader.addView(mTvCrump,mNavigationHistory.size()-1);
```

Now i want to make my own LinearLayout class like this:

```
public class Breadcrump extends LinearLayout {

    private List<? super Item> mNavigationHistory = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private List<TextView> mElements = new ArrayList<TextView>();

    public Breadcrump(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public Breadcrump(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

    public void addElement (String name) {

    }

}
```

my xml looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/cell_selected"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

      <com.client.views.Breadcrump
        android:id="@+id/ll_breadcrump"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

and use it like this:

```
mLlHeader = (Breadcrump)view.findViewById(R.id.ll_breadcrump);
....
```

**EDIT**

i now added the namespace in the layout xml file where i use my custom view and a new Constructor in the view class with an attribute set. Now the app starts. But it displays only my custom view and the rest of the layout is white ?

Comment: Depending on what your requirements are, you might be interested in this class: [`FragmentBreadCrumbs`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentBreadCrumbs.html)

Comment: i had small look at this, but i thought its allready to sepcific for my usecase.

Comment: ok i finally did it by at last set the layout sizes to "wrap_content" ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your layout XML file, you probably have something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll_header"
    ... />
```

Try changing it to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.client.views.Breadcrump
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll_header"
    ... />
```

**EDIT: how to use it in your activity?**

If your XML layout file is called *main.xml*, then just call `setContentView(R.layout.main)` in the `onCreate()` method of your activity. Your `Breadcrump` gets initialized internally. Then you can get a reference to it with `(Breadcrump)view.findViewById(R.id.ll_header)`.

Comment: when i do it like this i get a xml error

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.client.views.Breadcrump
    android:id="@+id/ll_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    />`

Comment: the eror is `unbound prefix`

Comment: Looks like you're missing the `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`. Please take a look at the edit I made to the answer.

Comment: i didn't want to post this so i changed it

Comment: Ok, I have deleted it. Please check the edit where I explain how to get a reference to the `Breadcrump`.

Comment: don't i need to call the constructor then ?

Comment: No, the instance of the object is created internally. If you need a reference to it, you can get it by calling the `findViewById()` method.